# freebsd open source kernel

Tags: open-source, freebsd

I am beginner. I want install freebsd on VM and test open source world! I want to write a small function and to put it into kernel of OS, and then I want to use it in another program as a system function.
I just installed freebsd11 on VM. I know a command line environment! I should use a GUI? Where is kernel?

Answer (score 1):

[FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/) is a wonderful beast once you know all its capabilities, if you want to play with [jails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD_jail), [ZFS](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/zfs.html) and build your own [kernels](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/kernelconfig-building.html), probably this already build image can be a good starting point: 
https://fabrik.red/post/test/ more info can be found here including scripts about how to create your own images/jails (custom kernel): https://github.com/fabrik-red/images

There is no GUI on the images, and maybe you will never need one, unless you want to use FreeBSD as a desktop, but FreeBSD shines more on headless systems (no GUI).

**Update**:

For GUI probably you can give a try to [trueos.org](https://www.trueos.org/) or you can install your own [Xorg](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/x-install.html), [desk environments](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/x11-wm.html)

Comment: FreeBSD use x11 in ports. I personally use FreeBSD with X11 + OpenBox and it works without issues. Many FreeBSD forks exists with integrated X11 by default like PCBSD (http://pcbsd.org/) and GhostBSD (http://ghostbsd.org/). So... If you have your habits from Windows, Mac or Linux, you can use GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should learn a bit more about what the operating system does before trying to modify the kernel. There are lots of resources about the unix kernels. See the developers handbook, https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/ or just google and you will find many resources.

Comment: I like to see it in a simple work. I should has a GUI now?

Comment: You don't need a gui although it will probably make your life easier. Take a look a chapter's 8 in the developer handbook. It explains how to compile custom kernels. Take a look at this article for creating your own module to add into the kernel http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/writing_a_kernel_module_for_freebsd/